# Order of hoisting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hoisting

```
function g () {
    var x;
    function y () {};
    var z;
}
```

I would like to know exactly what order the above code becomes when hoisted.

**Theory 1:** Order between `var`s and `function`s remains as-is:

```
function g () {
    var x;
    function y () {};
    var z;
}
```

**Theory 2:** `var`s come before `function`s:

```
function g () {
    var x;
    var z;
    function y () {};
}
```

**Theory 3:** `function`s come before `var`s:

```
function g () {
    function y () {};
    var x;
    var z;
}
```

Which theory is correct?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Functions are hoisted first, then variable declarations, per [ECMAScript 5, section 10.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5) which specifies how hoisting happens:

We first have step 5 handling function declarations:

> For each FunctionDeclaration f in code, in source text order do...

Then step 8 handles `var` declarations:

> For each VariableDeclaration and VariableDeclarationNoIn d in code, in source text order do...

So, functions are given higher priority than `var` statements, since the later `var` statements cannot overwrite a previously-handled function declaration.
 (Substep 8c enforces the condition "If varAlreadyDeclared is false, then [continue...]" so extant variable bindings are not overwritten.)

You can also [see this experimentally](http://jsfiddle.net/rrn3v378/):

```js
function f(){}
var f;
console.log(f);

var g;
function g(){}
console.log(g);
```

Both `log` calls show the function, not an `undefined` value.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, he is saying that `function`s come before `var`s, which is Theory 3 in the OP.

Comment: FWIW, this has changed some time in the latest versions. I believe the binding for both are now created at the same time (e.g. step 27) and at the end the actual function value is assigned (step 36). But I could be misreading this. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation

Comment: This is interesting for me why Ecma Scpesfication acept rule like that? What is reason give functions  higher priority than var statements?

Answer (score 10):

Although the *order* was fixed by the specification, as the accepted answer points out, that order really is not that important.

- `var` declarations are hoisted, but not their initialisation (if there is one). A `var` declaration is without effect if the name is already taken by a `function` or other `var` declaration.
- `function` definitions are hoisted -- not only declaring the name, but also their value, i.e. the function.

So the following two pieces of code:

```js
(function () {
    console.log(typeof a);
    var a = 1;
    function a() { }
})();
```

and:

```js
(function () {
    console.log(typeof a);
    function a() { }
    var a = 1;
})();
```

... translate to:

```js
(function () {
    function a() { }
    var a;
    console.log(typeof a);
    a = 1;
})();
```

and respectively:

```js
(function () {
    var a;
    function a() { }
    console.log(typeof a);
    a = 1;
})();
```

The latter two are the same thing really. If the engine processes the hoisted `var` declaration first, then `a` is first `undefined` but then immediately overwritten as function. If on the other hand the `function` definition is processed first, then the `var` declaration has no effect. In both scenarios the outcome is the same.