# Function declarations and variable declarations hoisted, which one hoisted first?

Tags: javascript

I came to know 'Function declarations and variable declarations are always moved (“hoisted”) invisibly to the top of their containing scope by the JavaScript interpreter.' -- [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

But which one hoisted first?

As a result of someone asked me at [SegmentFault](https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000008031450?_ea=1527624), I should give him a exact answer.

Comment: Practically speaking, what difference does it make?

Comment: How can that matter ? "Hoisting" is a confusing concept. It's simpler to see it this way: "the scope of a variable declared with var or a function declaration is  the whole function". Edit: thing which makes it more complex (and probably justifies the question) is that variable declaration moves with the assignation, contrary to the variable "equivalent".

Answer (score -1):

```
function test() {
   return foo;
   var foo = true;
   function foo(){}

}

console.log(typeof test()) // function
```

functions are hoisted first
[See here for more informations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246589/order-of-hoisting-in-javascript)

Comment: This is not hoisting

Comment: This doesn't prove anything. The assignment `foo = true` is never executed because the function returns beforehand.

Comment: The assignment is never executed indeed. This is about hoisting though

Comment: So, how does this example prove that functions are "hoisted first"? In other words, how does this prove that the order is `function foo() {}; var foo;` and not `var foo; function foo() {}` ?

Comment: Is my answer different from [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28246653/4949918) ?