# Why does NodeJS throw a TypeError not a function depending on where a function is defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, arrow-functions

I am transpiling an arrow function that looks like this:

```
const convertToSeconds = milliseconds => Math.round( milliseconds / 1000 );

function fixAllTimestamps( record ) {
  if ( record.lastAccessTime ) { record.lastAccessTime = convertToSeconds( record.lastAccessTime ); }

  if ( record.licenseExpires ) { record.licenseExpires = convertToSeconds( record.licenseExpires ); }

  if ( record.lastModifiedAt ) { record.lastModifiedAt = convertToSeconds( record.lastModifiedAt ); }

  if ( record.createdAt ) { record.createdAt = convertToSeconds( record.createdAt ); }
}
```

Babel seems to do the right thing, because the arrow function gets converted to:

```
var convertToSeconds = function convertToSeconds(milliseconds) {
  return Math.round(milliseconds / 1000);
};
```

However, when I run this code using node, I get this:

```
record.lastAccessTime = convertToSeconds(record.lastAccessTime);
                        ^

TypeError: convertToSeconds is not a function
    at fixAllTimestamps   (test.js:109:29)
```

This is an unexpected result.

To resolve this, I can either define the arrow function right up at the top of the source code file, before any other functions are defined in the regular Javascript way, or I can put the arrow function definition within the body of `fixAllTimestamps` so that it becomes a nested function.

Does anybody know why node would fail like this, or is there actually something wrong with my code?

Comment: No one really got the right answer, though @bkbooth's mention of hoisting led me to the correct answer. In Javascript the hoisting order of different declarations makes a difference. C.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246589/order-of-hoisting-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using function expression and not function declaration. If you use function declaration, the order of which a function is in your file doesn't matter, if you use function expression, then your function needs to be defined before you use it.

Instead of

```
var convertToSeconds = function convertToSeconds(milliseconds) {
  return Math.round(milliseconds / 1000);
};
```

Do

```
function convertToSeconds(milliseconds) {
  return Math.round(milliseconds / 1000);
};
```

Check out my code sample: https://runkit.com/donuts/594352eb72a32300116d5d5e
I'd also like to point out that your function (`fixAllTimestamps`) is not returning anything. I'm assuming you're hoping it mutates the record.

Comment: Arrow functions without a block body implicitly return the value of the expression. That's why the babel transpiled function in his example has an explicit return value.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the arrow function, I was referring to `fixAllTimestamps`.

Comment: Oh yep, that makes more sense.

Comment: @Perspective Thanks for your post. Unfortunately, I know how to get it to work already, and I wanted to know the whys. bkbooth's answer is more correct though not exactly right either. Re: returns, my personal convention is to use function declarations for cases where there will be side effects, and arrow functions when I want to use pure functions.

Comment: @ClintonChau Yea, it was an issue with hoisting, and when calling the function. I could have definitely done a better job of explaining, and re-reading the answer. If you took a look at the runkit example I was able to reproduce the issue. The function `fixAllTimestamps` was hoisted at top, but when you ran the function, the function `convertToSeconds` that it dependent on, was not declared or hoisted.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're assigning a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) to a variable, it needs to be defined before you use it. If you were using a normal [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) it would get [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), and therefore you can use it before it's declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about hoisting. This doesn't quite answer my question why it doesn't work, because in my source code, the function expression is declared **before** the function declaration that uses it. The key is actually that the `fixAllTimestamps()` function gets hoisted, and at the same time, while the `var convertToSeconds` is hoisted, its assignment of the function declaration is **not** hoisted but occurs in execution order. That is why the TypeError is not that `convertToSeconds` is undefined, but the TypeError is instead, `not a function`.

Comment: Oh yep, that makes sense. I was thrown by the last bit of your question, where you said you could define the arrow function at the top of the source file. It gave me the impression that you might have been using them in a different order. Hoisting of `fixAllTimestamps` makes sense though, good find