# do functional declaration are hoisted before the variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, var, hoisting

If functional declarations are hoisted before the variable declaration .In that case ,Why I am getting the functional definition instead of undefined.

```
function a(){}
var a;
console.log(a); // ƒ a(){}
```

I am expecting that the variable declaration will override the functional declaration and become undefined

Comment: "*MDN says that the functional declarations are hoisted before the variable declaration*" - where does it say that?

Comment: You can get your answer from here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53875467/are-function-declarations-really-hoisted-before-variable-declarations

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not assigning a value to a variable and in hoisting JS place an undefined value to a variable. undefined does not override any value, that's why you're getting a function.

```
function a(){}
var a=1;
console.log(a); // result will be 1
```

Comment: "*undefined does not override any value, that's why you're getting a function.*" this is incorrect - `x = 1; x = undefined;` trivially shows that the value of `x` is `undefined`. Moreover, hoisting a variable *doesn't reassign a value*. Which is the real reason why the value doesn't change.