# Confusion about Javascript Hoisting

Tags: javascript, hoisting, executioncontext

I thought I grasped the concept of hoisting, but the code below got me confused. How does it return 1? Will the second example() function be hoisted above the first one?

```js
function example() {
  return 9;
}

console.log(example());

function example() {
  return 1;
}
```

If a function declaration is hoisted in a compilation phase and a function expression is executed in the execution phase. How come the code below returns 7? Is it simply due to example expression being declared first?

```js
var example = function() {
  return 7;
}

console.log(example());

function example() {
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just implicitly move every `function example` declaration to the top of your code; replacing any previous `function` of the same name. *Everything else*, including `var example = ...`, happens afterwards. That's hoisting, and that explains the behaviour perfectly.

Comment: So the replacement happens?   In the first example `function example()...` with value 9 will be hoisted first and then `function example()...` with a value of 1 will replace it right?                                                                               
And in the second example, we would hoist the `function example() ...` first, then when the `var example = ...` executes it will replace the hoisted one, therefore returning 7. Did I understand it right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @deceze While you are technically correct (the best kind of correct!), you say it as if `var` doesn't get hoisted, which it does.

I think the better answer is that functions gets hoisted before vars.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28246653/1497533

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `var example = function()` is getting called instead of `function example()` is the order of hoisting.

> Functions are hoisted first, then variable declarations, per
> [ECMAScript 5, section 10.5](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-10.5) which specifies how hoisting happens.

Read more here: [Order of hoisting in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246589/order-of-hoisting-in-javascript/28246653#28246653)

Comment: So to clarify, since `function example()` gets hoisted first and `var example = ...` is second. `var example = ...` replaces the `function example()` right?

Comment: @RomaKim Yes, exactly. However you have to write `var` first and then `function`. If you switch this order it will call `function` since var can not overwrite the function declaration. There is a good example here (with g and f): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246589/order-of-hoisting-in-javascript/28246653#28246653 Just keep in mind that the declaration is something different then hoisting.

Comment: I've looked at the example, but I'm still a little bit confused. From what I understand, `function declaration` will always have higher hoisting priority over `function expression`. Since `var` can't overwrite the `function declaration`, `function declaration` will always be logged first if declared before 'var'. In my second example, `example is 0` during compilation phase, but then `var` overwrites it during execution phase, therefore making `example = 7` and console logging `7`. I think I understand now. @LarsFlieger Thank you so much!